# After Double starting of Infinite soundPool, stop() function not work.Why?

Tags: android, soundpool

following code:

```
protected void gPlaySound(){
    globalSoundPool.play(globalSoundIDCoin,gVolume,gVolume,1,-1, (float) 0.5);
}

public void gStop() {
    globalSoundPool.stop(globalSoundIDCoin);
}
```

if, I call double gPlaySound() method, stop() method stopped to working. why?

Answer (score 0):

stop method stops the soundPool by streemingId no by soundID. Have to add following code:

```
int streamingId;
protected void gPlaySound(){
    streamingId = globalSoundPool.play(globalSoundIDCoin, gVolume, gVolume, 1, -1, (float) 2.0);
}
public void gStop() {
        globalSoundPool.stop(streamingId);
    }
```